# Image not appearing in HTML but Inspector?

Tags: html, image, css

I have following code as you also can see in attached screenshot:

```
<img class="deliveryIcon delivered"/>
```

**CSS**:

```
.delivered {
    background: url("../images/icons/ic_done_all_white_48dp_2x.png") no-repeat;
}
```

The image does not appear on rendered HTML.

I suspected the path is not correct but the image appears correctly on Inspector.

Can anyone suggest me what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Used `span` tag instead of `img` tag. You can not set background in `img` tag. Right systax for img tag is like this : `<img src="image.png" />`

Comment: Reading from other SO post, it should work using img and move the `src` to  CSS..

Comment: why can't you try with `src` attribute, why do you need  background-image?

Comment: Do you mean `src` inside css or html?

Answer (score 3):

Try this . Hope this will work

```
<img class="deliveryIcon delivered"/>
<style>
    .delivered {
        min-height:200px;
        min-width:200px;
     background-image: url("../images/icons/ic_done_all_white_48dp_2x.png");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set image height that is

```
.delivered {
    background: url("../images/icons/ic_done_all_white_48dp_2x.png") no-repeat;
height: 96px;
display: block;
}
```